# bootstrap-star-rating plugin causes an error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rating is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, plugins, bower

I've installed the [plugin](http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating) via bower and included it into bower.json file: `bower install bootstrap-star-rating --save`. In the view (it's a Rails project) I have this piece of code:

```
<%= form.text_field :rating,
                            id: :review_rating,
                            class: 'form-item large-6 cell',
                            placeholder: 'Rating*',
                            required: true %>
```

My js is compiled by gulp into `public/layout` and it is present in `application.js`. In `config/application.rb` I have this piece of code:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('public', 'layout')
```

So, the `layout` directory is present in assets pipeline.
 The code I use to initialize star-rating is:

```
$('#review_rating').rating({
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        size: 'sm',
        theme: 'krajee-uni'
    });
```

Why am I getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).rating is not a function`, if the plugin is present in `bower.json` as a dependency?

Comment: Check your actual markup. JQuery must be present ABOVE any other Javascript plugins. i.e. you must reference the JQuery.min.js script first in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function triggering the error is present at row `498` of the [**bootstrap star-rating**](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating/blob/master/js/star-rating.js#L498) github repository

```
$.fn.rating = function (option) {
    var args = Array.apply(null, arguments), retvals = [];
    args.shift();
    this.each(function () {
        var self = $(this), data = self.data('rating'), options = typeof option === 'object' && option,
            theme = options.theme || self.data('theme'), lang = options.language || self.data('language') || 'en',
            thm = {}, loc = {}, opts;
        if (!data) {
            if (theme) {
                thm = $.fn.ratingThemes[theme] || {};
            }
            if (lang !== 'en' && !$h.isEmpty($.fn.ratingLocales[lang])) {
                loc = $.fn.ratingLocales[lang];
            }
            opts = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.rating.defaults, thm, $.fn.ratingLocales.en, loc, options, self.data());
            data = new Rating(this, opts);
            self.data('rating', data);
        }

        if (typeof option === 'string') {
            retvals.push(data[option].apply(data, args));
        }
    });
    switch (retvals.length) {
        case 0:
            return this;
        case 1:
            return retvals[0] === undefined ? this : retvals[0];
        default:
            return retvals;
    }
};
```

The function is not included in your asset pipeline.
The `star-rating.js` file is not included in your `application.js`

To test this just run your server `rails s`, open your page, then with `f12` open the chrome developer toolbar and search for that file in the sources section.

[image]

With ruby on rails I don't use bower to install plugins and maybe it is just enought to include all the relevant js, css files and images inside your `application.js`, `.scss` and inside the proper folder for your images.

https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating

If you have any additional issues let me know.

Comment: I decided just to put proper js and css files to a vendor directory, and now everything is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi Great!